# IAM policy for VPC security groups when creating a DB instance in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Is there a way I can force users to only select specified VPC security groups when creating an RDS instance? I can do this with DB security groups because there are resource-level permissions available for those, but my users will need VPC security groups and the documentation does not show how to achieve this at the RDS resource level with an IAM policy.

Comment: I don't believe there is a straightforward way to achieve. One way you can do this is to assign permissions to create RDS instance with security group having a specific tag key and value in security group. This can be achieved using custom tag conditions. Refer this AWS link for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.Conditions.html#UsingWithRDS.IAM.SpecifyingCustomTags

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 this only works for DB security groups. The problem is that I'm not using DB security groups, I'm using VPC security groups that the DB instance will reside in. When you create a DB instance, you select a VPC security group for that instance, and I want to use an IAM policy to enforce an explicit denial of creating an instance when a specific VPC security group is not selected.